# How to run a query in php, on which WHERE value is not selected?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So i am trying to make a filter for a sql table. So essentially user selects multiple drop-downs, and i run the query to sql based on those values.

So this is how i populate my dropdowns:

```
<?php
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
$sql = "SELECT [EQUIP TYPE] as EQUIPTYPE, PROPERTY, AUTOMATEDSYSTEM FROM TrimTable";
$query = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
if ($query === false)
{  
    echo "Could not link to SQL Server";
}
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))
{   
    $EQUIPTYPE[] = "$row[EQUIPTYPE]";
    $PROPERTY[] = "$row[PROPERTY]"; 
    $AUTOMATEDSYSTEM[] = "$row[AUTOMATEDSYSTEM]";
}
echo "<div><table class='SearchBox'>";
echo "<thead></thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";
        echo "<tr>";
            $EQUIPTYPE_unique = array_unique($EQUIPTYPE);
            sort($EQUIPTYPE_unique);
            echo "<td>Equip Type</td>";
            echo "<td><select style='width: 110px;' name='EquipType'>";
            echo "<option selected='selected' value='%'>Select</option>";
            foreach($EQUIPTYPE_unique as $key => $value):
                echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
            endforeach;
            echo "</select></td>";


            $PROPERTY_unique = array_unique($PROPERTY);
            sort($PROPERTY_unique);
            echo "<td>Property</td>";
            echo "<td><select style='width: 110px;' name='PropertyOption'>";
            echo "<option selected='selected' value='%'>Select</option>";
            foreach($PROPERTY_unique as $key => $value):
                echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
            endforeach;
            echo "</select></td>";

            $AUTOMATEDSYSTEM_unique = array_unique($AUTOMATEDSYSTEM);
            sort($AUTOMATEDSYSTEM_unique);                        
            echo "<td>Automated System</td>";
            echo "<td><select style='width: 110px;' name='AutomatedSystem'>";
            echo "<option selected='selected' value='%'>Select</option>";
            foreach($AUTOMATEDSYSTEM_unique as $key => $value):
                echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
            endforeach;
            echo "</select></td>";   
        echo "</tr>";
    echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Now once dropdown is selected i have a search button, which executes new php code which looks like this:

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION['AutomatedSystem'] = $_POST['AutomatedSystem'];
$AutomatedSystemOp = $_SESSION['AutomatedSystem'];
$_SESSION['PropertyOption'] = $_POST['PropertyOption'];
$PropertyOp = $_SESSION['PropertyOption'];
$_SESSION['EquipType'] = $_POST['EquipType'];
$EquipTypeOp = $_SESSION['EquipType'];

$conn = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=mzrefd39,1433;Database=ger_mapv', $username, $password);
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT TAG,DESCRIPTION FROM TrimTable WHERE [AUTOMATED SYSTEM] LIKE ? AND [EQUIP TYPE] LIKE ? AND PROPERTY LIKE ? ORDER BY TAG");
$sth->execute(array($AutomatedSystemOp, $EquipTypeOp, $PropertyOp));
$data = $sth->fetchAll();

$length = count($data);
for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++)
{
    // This is where i just arrange the data way I want to?
} 

?>
```

Now here is the question, it could be that one my dropdowns on the first set of code is not selected, so its left to its default state "Select", value= "%". Which would mean when running the query for the data in the table(second block) it looks through everything (%). Is there a way, I can give it a value that it doesnt look for it at all(since dont care about the field). I would feel like that would be faster? Is that possible?

**UPDATE**

I guess i am not clear. I have three options. Lets say i select value for EQUIPTYPE and AUTOMATEDSYSTEM. I leave PROPERTY to its default value which is select. So when my second block of code runs, it only runs for EQUIPTYPE and AUTOMATEDSYSTEM, and the third value PROPERTY is %, which doesnt need to run.

Comment: Sure. Just don't put it in your query.

Comment: ^ or put a limit on it, such as `limit 25` etc.. so it only grabs the first n results. If you have an auto-increment ID you could do `where id=0` which will never happen and thus give you an empty result.   But the best way is to not do the search if some min search requirement is not met, it all depends on the behavior you want.

Comment: What I do a lot of times is build an where array ... such as `$where[] = 'id = :id'` then you can check if `empty($where)` and not do the search and if you do have some just do `$sql .= implode(' AND ', $where );`

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix, can you point to an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure here is a simple example ( untested )

Say we have these select:

```
<select name="id" >
   <option value="" > - Pick an ID- </option>  <!-- default value -->
   <option value="1" > ID One </option>
</select>

<select name="color" >
   <option value="" > - Pick an Color- </option>  <!-- default value -->
   <option value="red" > Red </option>
</select>
```

Then in php we can do this

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE';
$where = array();
$param = array();

if ( !empty( $_POST['id'] ) ){
     //id is empty '' by default
     $where[] = 'id = :id';
     $param[':id'] = $_POST['id'];
}

if ( !empty( $_POST['color'] ) ){
     //color is empty '' by default
     $where[] = 'color = :color';
     $param[':color'] = $_POST['color'];
}

///etc ...

$result = array();
if( !empty( $where ) ){
     $stmt = $sth->prepare( $sql . implode( ' AND ', $where ));
     $stmt->execute( $param );
     $result = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
}else{
      //do some thing for no search>?
}

return $result;
```

It's much cleaner and very easy to add additional `$where` elements, the only downside is if you have more complex queries, or things that need both `AND` and  `OR`.